# json output page error can not be read data from json

Tags: php, json, output

```
<?php
$url = "site.com/json"; //JSON output if i am visit using url
$h = [
    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
     ];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $h);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
?>
```

when i visit the json url above using browser the output that comes out is json data. (no issue)
but when i use curl or file get content that comes out an error.

this output if i am using curl or file getcontent

```
��}�r���pTe���I\��Ó�-�D�ر��$S�%�Bh�m��&-+.W�k��͓��I�E�IQrK��7�q�XX{��� wz�d��ǯ�㿿�y i���O̰���,\�/e��1\VRH������o�G�}�u?b&� ��(��Oܗ���|:�\'���P!x==��|<�{�ݩ�����`.��Y�z���u�#��B�?���@���
```

Are url json not support call using curl or file getcontent oof php?

Comment: because the targeted url `site.com/json`  doesn't return any json

Comment: I visited on that URL with firefox browser but no json

Comment: who upvoted this question? down vote it

Comment: @NalinNishant What? Why downvote it? Seems like a legitimate question/problem.

Comment: returned content seems to be compressed. Try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');` to allow curl to make decompression automatically

Comment: yes your question is legitimate but when I try to visit on your JSON site `site.com/json` with firefox browser it shows an HTML page rather than JSON and you claimed that it returns JSON when visit through browser